# UITextView number of lines when not showing full text (ios7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a `UITextView` that is not showing all the text in it so you need to scroll to read more. i would like to get the number of lines in the `UITextView`. I tried to find how but all i could find is only if you show all the text to get the number of lines.

autoLayout is on.

my code look like this:

```
CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 124.0f);
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
[self contentSizeRectForTextView:textView];
textView.text=@"very long text";
```

i have tried:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
CGSize size = [textView.text sizeWithFont:font
                        constrainedToSize:textView.frame.size
                            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
float numberOfLines = size.height / font.lineHeight;
NSLog(@"%f", numberOfLines);
```

but it gives only the number of lines showed as well as:

```
float rows = round( (textView.contentSize.height - textView.textContainerInset.top - textView.textContainerInset.bottom) / textView.font.lineHeight );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear. Are you looking to determine the number of lines that are visible in the text view based on its current size or do you want to know how many lines of text (both visible and currently hidden) are in the text view?

Comment: I want to know how many lines of text (both visible and currently hidden), with Benjibun answer i managed to show all text, get the number of lines and the resize it again, there should be a better way i believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this!

```
int numLines = textview.contentSize.height / textview.font.lineHeight;
```

re-adjust frame:

```
CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
textView.frame = newFrame;

textview.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: It returns only the number of lines that are shown in the textView frame

Comment: It will work only if autoLayout is off and im using it on, ill update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIScrollView and add UITextView as subview. In this case scroll will change size according to text inside UITextView